# Prevent toggle all items

Tags: php, jquery

I have this line of code in an for loop:

```
echo '<toggle_me style="display: none"><img align="center" src="images/icon/pdf_mail.png" /></a></toggle_me>';
```

With this jQuery:

```
<script>
$("img").click(function ()
{
    $("toggle_me").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Ofcourse this toggles all images, how can I only toggle the one clicked?

Comment: Your HTML seems to be broken, there is no opening <a> and <toggle_me> is not a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually made up your own HMTL tag? You crazy? Please read up about [Classes and IDs](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/), you then use those css selectors in jQuery to select the togglers/imgs.

For example:

```
<div class="toggler">
    <img src="..." />
    <span>Toggle</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.toggler span').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

That's a very quick solution that should work for you, I highly recommend reading up about classes/ids and selectors and you will easily see how you could improve this code for your needs.

Comment: Thx for explaining this to me. Fow to start with the image hidden? I have tried event.preventDefault(); but that won't work.

Comment: $('.toggler img').hide();  will hide them all if JS is enabled.

Comment: I'm not gettign any result with $('.toggler img').hide(); even when put in an ready(function(). And I think that will hide all images and just the ones that can be toggled.

Comment: It will hide all 'img' tags inside elements with a class of 'toggler'. If not you could just use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$(this).parent().toggle();` instead of `$("toggle_me").toggle();`

Better would be to add the click event on the toggle_me element...